# Remove extra entry from rEFIt

Tags: linux, macos

I created an extra partition in my macbook and then updated refit. After I couldn't start linux from usb again. Also after deleting partition entry is still appearing.

I allredy tried to reinstall refit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute this line in os x terminal

```
sudo fdisk -u /dev/disk0
```

Comment: This just literally saved my life. Well, my thesis, which is my future. I stand by it, "life" is pretty accurate :D Thanks! (Ubuntu wouldn't boot with the extra entry still active)